# Password protect Github websites - Google search results showing

Tags: github, passwords, github-pages, password-protection

I used this
https://github.com/matteobrusa/Password-protection-for-static-pages
to password protect a Github website

but i noticed that internal pages show in Google search results.  So technically, anyone can access the website without password.

Is there any way I can prevent internal pages from showing on Google search results?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

in your `head` of the HTML file. In addition, you can add the page to your disallow/noindex of your `robots.txt` file as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /404.html 
Noindex:  /404.html
```